# Process large text files by cleaning them and splitting into new lines depending on delimiter

Tags: sed

I have a bunch of text files with the same name in multiple directories that look like this:

```
"[['master', 'planning', 'occur', 'many', 'scale'], ['age', 'smart', 'city', 'municipal']]"
```

I need to split each line whenever a "[" occurs to a new line until a "] occurs:

```
"[['master', 'planning', 'occur', 'many', 'scale']
['age', 'smart', 'city', 'municipal']]"
```

I now want to perform some data cleaning where I remove all special characters:

```
sed s/"'"/""/g m.txt > m1.txt
sed s/'"'/''/g m1.txt > m2.txt
sed s/\]//g m2.txt > m3.txt
sed 's/\[//g' m3.txt > m4.txt
sed s/,//g m4.txt > m5.txt
sed s/\`//g m5.txt > m6.txt
sed 's/\.//g' m6.txt > m7.txt
```

Which results in this:

```
master planning occur many scale age smart city municipal
```

While my actual desired result would be this:

```
master planning occur many scale 
age smart city municipal
```

My questions are now the following:

1. How can I do this split for all lines (I don't know how many [...] constructions are the per line.
   and
2. How can I summarize all commands after that into one little neat script?

```
sed -e s/"'"/""/g -e s/'"'/''/g -e s/\]//g -e 's/\[//g' -e s/,//g -e s/\`//g -e 's/\.//g' m.txt > m_1.txt
```

works for 2!!

Comment: sed -e 's/ \[/\n\[/' -e s/"'"/""/g -e s/'"'/''/g -e s/\]//g -e 's/\[//g' -e s/,//g -e s/\`//g -e 's/\.//g' m.txt > m_1.txt should do all in one (the first sed adds \n whenever there is a space and a [ that are together) - tested on Bash GNU bash, version 4.2.46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a perl string representing a perl array of arrays. If that's the case, you could do:

```
$ perl -l -0777 -ne '
  eval "\$string = $_";
  eval "\$list = $string";
  print join " ", @{$_} for @$list' your-file
master planning occur many scale
age smart city municipal
```

Otherwise, if it's just about changing `], [`'s to newline and delete all `` []'`", `` characters:

```
$ sed 's/\], \[/\
/g; s/[]["'\''`,]//g' your-file
master planning occur many scale
age smart city municipal
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ":a;s/(\[[^]]*\]+),? /\1\n/;s/[]'\",[]//;ta" input_file
master planning occur many scale
age smart city municipal
```